# Incremental column depening on column value

Tags: mysql, count, auto-increment

I would like to have a column which has an incremental integer depending on the column value after sorting the table.

E.g. after sorting by state:

```
Nr  | State      | Counter
---------------------------
234 | Alberta    | 1
534 | Alberta    | 2
111 | Alberta    | 3
123 | California | 1
876 | New York   | 1
101 | New York   | 2
542 | New York   | 3
533 | New York   | 4
```

Is this even possible with MySQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just found the solution after banging my head into the wall:

```
SELECT
  t.*,
  @row := IF(@lastState = t.State, @row + 1, 0) as counter,
  @lastFunkt := t.State
FROM
  table t,
  (SELECT @row := 0,
          @lastState := '') SQLVars
```

Comment: I seriously doubt you found this banging your head, against anything ;)